# installing setzler / eventStudy R package gives error "non-zero exit status"

Tags: r, package, devtools

When I tried to install "setzler/eventStudy" package from github. the following happens-

```
 devtools::install_github("setzler/eventStudy/eventStudy")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version of Rtools compatible with R 3.6.1 was found. (Only the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:4.0)
```

Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
Downloading GitHub repo setzler/eventStudy@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All
2: CRAN packages only
3: None
4: zoo (1.8-8 -> 1.8-9) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:1
zoo (1.8-8 -> 1.8-9) [CRAN]
Installing 1 packages: zoo

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
binary source needs_compilation
zoo  1.8-8  1.8-9              TRUE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/zoo_1.8-8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1096180 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

package ‘zoo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\ahad1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpcr8MgA\downloaded_packages
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version of Rtools compatible with R 3.6.1 was found. (Only the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:4.0)

Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\ahad1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpcr8MgA\remotes5100354379db\setzler-eventStudy-382c5ad\eventStudy/DESCRIPTION' ...

- preparing 'eventStudy':
  √  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
- checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
- checking for empty or unneeded directories
  Removed empty directory 'eventStudy/inst/figures'
- building 'eventStudy_1.0.tar.gz'

- installing *source* package 'eventStudy' ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error: (converted from warning) package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.6.3
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'eventStudy'
- removing 'E:/R-3.6.1/library/eventStudy'
  Error: Failed to install 'eventStudy' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/ahad1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcr8MgA/file510043cc4ec3/eventStudy_1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

How do I resolve it.

Comment: You are using R-3.6.1 and Rtools 4.0. Try updating R to R-4.0.4 or downgrade Rtools to Rtools 3.5.